# Reading File through ifstream with delimiters

Tags: c++, string, delimiter, ifstream

I am trying to read from a textfile that includes the id, name, and description of an item. They are delimited by the '-' character. The code works for the first line, but for the rest of the lines, only the ID is read properly while the name and description are blank.
Here is a snippet from the data text file that I am reading from.

items.txt file:

```
1080000 - White Ninja Gloves - (no description)
1080001 - Red Ninja Gloves - (no description)
1080002 - Black Ninja Gloves - (no description)
1081000 - Red Ninja Gloves - (no description)
```

This is my code:

```
void GetItemData()
        {
            std::ifstream File("items.txt");
            std::string TempString;
            while (File.good())
            {
                ItemData itemData;
                getline(File, TempString);
                size_t pos = TempString.find('-');
                itemData.ID = stoi(TempString.substr(0, pos));
                size_t pos2 = TempString.find('-', pos + 1);
                itemData.name = TempString.substr(pos + 1, pos2 - (pos + 1));
                itemData.description = TempString.substr(pos2 + 1, TempString.length() - 1);
                itemsList.push_back(itemData);
            }
        }
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Have you used a debugger so far? Or at least printed some values in the iterations, like `TempString` after `getline`, and the substrings?

Comment: In any case, you should split up the tasks. Have a function which creates an entry from a line. Far easier to debug, as you can test things separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `std::list<ItemData> itemsList;` from your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct ItemData {
    int ID;
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
};

std::vector<ItemData> itemsList;

void GetItemData() {
    std::ifstream File("items.txt");
    std::string TempString;    
    while (File.good()) {
        ItemData itemData;
        getline(File, TempString);
        size_t pos = TempString.find('-');
        itemData.ID = stoi(TempString.substr(0, pos));
        size_t pos2 = TempString.find('-', pos + 1);
        itemData.name = TempString.substr(pos + 1, pos2 - (pos + 1));
        itemData.description = TempString.substr(pos2 + 1, TempString.length() - 1);
        itemsList.push_back(itemData);
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ItemData& item) {
    os << item.ID << " - " << item.name << " - " << item.description;
    return os;
}

void PrintFile() {
    GetItemData();
    std::ofstream file("out.txt");
    for(auto line : itemsList) {
        file << line << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    PrintFile();
    return 0;
}
```

I debug the code and it words for me, if this does not work for you, something else went wrong.

Comment: Yeah that wasn't the issue.. I had an external vector declared as well, but printing it out to anotherfile with just the ID and name still resulted in the same thing.

Comment: @RodneyMuller I have just edited the source code, now it works for me. If it not works for you, should give me further code.

Comment: I just fixed the issue. It turned out that I wasn't printing to my listview properly haha. I forgot to increment the placeholder for adding an item to the listview for the names. You were right in that it was something else. Thank you for your answer!